# Android studio: Using calender to reset steps taken for that day

Tags: java, android, calendar, reset

I'm quite new to Java however I'm building small fitness app and I am stuck on how I would go about resetting the number of steps taken when it hits midnight using Calender object. I'm trying to get the steps reset at 12:00 but save the steps that are there into my shared preference at 23:59. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

This is what I have so far in regards to using Calander:

```
  public String getTheDate (){
    date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);

 }
```

I'm a bit stuck so I would be really grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to run the services with alarm manager in the background and 23:59 you have to clear your data

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give that a try.